# I have a visa for Belgium. Is it required for Paris too?

Tags: visas

Do I need a separate visa to visit Paris, if I have a visa to visit Belgium?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of one of our existing Schengen visa questions? Could somebody who's familiar with them suggest the right one?

Comment: Don't understand why the question has been given a negative vote. The question is clear and perhaps a very simple one, but I asked it here as the answer of the question was as such unavailable anywhere else and I needed to decide about booking the tickets. Any suggestions to edit the question are always welcome. Those who have given a negative vote should also give suggestions for improvement

Comment: The downvote wasn't mine, but it's probably for lack of research. It shouldn't be hard to find out that your Schengen visa is valid for the whole Shengen zone, which includes France.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are good. Visa for any country of the Schengen area are good for the whole area.

Comment: Unless it is a (rare) LTV visa that excludes travel to France.

Comment: It is a short term visa for conference